# FEventType.ChildAdded event only fired once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

my firebase data structure looks like the following

```
user
  |__{user_id}
      |__userMatch
            |__{userMatchId}
                  |__createdAt: <UNIX time in milliseconds>
```

I'm trying to listen for the child added event under `userMatch` since a particular given time. Here's my swift code:

```
func listenForNewUserMatches(since: NSDate) -> UInt? {
    NSLog("listenForNewUserMatches since: \(since)")
    var handle:UInt?
    let userMatchRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath("\(user.objectId!)/userMatch")
    var query = userMatchRef.queryOrderedByChild("createdAt");
    query = query.queryStartingAtValue(since.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    handle = query.observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let userMatchId = snapshot.key
        NSLog("New firebase UserMatch created \(userMatchId)")
    }, withCancelBlock:  { error in
        NSLog("Error listening for new userMatches: \(error)")
    })
    return handle
}
```

What's happening is that the event call back is called only once. Subsequent data insertion under `userMatch` didn't trigger the call. Sort of behaves like `observeSingleEventOfType`

I have the following data inserted into firebase under user/{some-id}/userMatch:

```
QGgmQnDLUB
    createdAt: 1448934387867
bMfJH1bzNs  
    createdAt: 1448934354943
```

Here are the logs:

```
2015-11-30 17:32:38.632 listenForNewUserMatches since:2015-12-01 01:32:37 +0000
2015-11-30 17:45:55.163 New firebase UserMatch created bMfJH1bzNs
```

The call back was fired for `bMfJH1bzNs` but not for `QGgmQnDLUB` which was added at a later time. It's very consistent: after opening the app, it only fires for the first event. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Update: Actually the behavior is not very consistent. Sometimes the call back is not fired at all, not even once. But since I persist the `since` time I should use when calling `listenForNewUserMatches` function. If I kill the app and restart the app, the callback will get fired (`listenForNewUserMatches` is called upon app start), for the `childAdded` event before I killed the app. This happens very consistently (callback always called upon kill-restart the app for events that happened prior to killing the app).

Update 2: Don't know why, but if I add `queryLimitedToLast` to the query, it works all the time now. I mean, by changing `userMatchRef.queryOrderedByChild("createdAt")` to `userMatchRef.queryOrderedByChild("createdAt").queryLimitedToLast(10)`, it's working now. `10` is just an arbitrary number I chose.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from the nature of time based data.

You created a query that says: "*Get me all the matches that happened after now.*" This should work when the app is running and new data comes in like `bMfJH1bzNs`. But older data like `QGgmQnDLUB` won't show up.

Then when you run again, the `since.timeIntervalSince1970` has changed to a later date. Now neither of the objects before will show up in your query.

When you changed your query to use `queryLimitedToLast` you avoided this issue because you're no longer querying based on time. Now your query says: "*Get me the last ten children at this location.*"

As long as there is data at that location you'll always receive data in the callback.

So you either need to ensure that `since.timeIntervalSince1970` is always earlier than the data you expect to come back, or use `queryLimitedToLast`.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Actually `QGgmQnDLUB` (happened at 1448934387867) was newer data by about 30 seconds than `bMfJH1bzNs` (happened at 1448934354943). That's why I feel either I'm not using the API correctly or there's a bug with Firebase SDK.